# Recombination frequency as a function of genomic location in E coli?

Tags: ecoli, database, recombination

Are there any databases or papers that give recombination frequency as a function of position in the E coli genome?

Comment: What kind of recombination do you mean?

Comment: Homologous recombination.

Comment: No, I mean: which process? [There are several processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homologous_recombination#In_bacteria) involving recombination in bacteria, which require enzymes and different substrates. For example, recombination-mediated DNA repair occurs at sites of DNA damage (which can happen at any location, albeit with unequal frequencies), while [conjugational recombination](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11101815) is much more location-bound.

Answer (score 4):

A recombination map of the E. coli genome was [recently published](https://academic.oup.com/bib/article-abstract/22/4/bbaa335/6034796?redirectedFrom=fulltext) (several years after question was asked).